# Quelles prépositions avec “emprunter” et “acheter” ?

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions

Comme tout le monde, mon oreille et mon intuition à moi se sont développées dans l’environnement de ma langue maternelle, à savoir l’anglais. Et je me demande si c’est dû à cette influence que les expressions *emprunter à* et *acheter à* me semblent singulières.

Ma perspective c’est que le mot *à* s’emploie pour indiquer les destinations et que c’est le mot *de* qui s’emploie pour indiquer les sources. Alors, dans la conversation :

> Tu y es allé en voiture ?
> Oui, j’en ai emprunté une **à** une copine.

cette intuition m’aurait prédit que la forme correcte serait
**J’en ai emprunté une **d**´une copine*,
car c’est en ma possession à moi que l’auto est entrée (pour un temps),
tandis que ma copine est celle à partir de laquelle je l’ai reçue.
(Si je ne me trompe pas, *emprunter une d’une copine*
signifie en réalité emprunter [à un prêteur non précisé] une [voiture] qui appartient à une copine. C’est ça ?)

Pareillement, dans la conversation :

> Où as-tu eu la bagnole ?
> Ah, je l’ai achetée **à** un collègue de travail.

la préposition me semble l’inverse de ce que nécessite la logique.
J’aurais cru que l’emploi apte serait
**Je l’ai achetée **d**´un collègue de travail*.

En effet, ma logique semble être à l’œuvre dans le cas de l’antonyme *vendre* :

> Tu n’as plus de voiture ?
> Non, je l’ai vendue **au** boulanger.

même si l’interlocuteur pourrait bien répondre,

> Sans déc, il **te** l’a achetée **à** toi ?

J’imagine que mon intuition me fourvoie. Quelle serait l’intuition des francophones à cet égard ?
La notion des sources et des destinations ne s’applique pas à ces verbes ? Si tel est le cas, y a-t-il d’autres verbes semblables ?
Je ne crois pas, par exemple, qu’on **reçoive** quelque chose **à** quelqu’un.

Answer (score 1):

***Acheter de*** se disait autrefois :

> *Je payerai en outre la somme de 5,000 fr. pour l acquisition du presbytère que je veux **acheter de M. Bodin** tant en mon nom qu'au nom de mes successeurs à perpétuité.*
> *Précis pour M. l'abbé Cholet*, 1842

Il a été peu à peu supplanté par ***acheter à*** à partir du début du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Peut-être que la préposition ***de*** a été délaissée dans cet usage parce qu'elle était aussi utilisée pour indiquer la source du financement (*acheter **de** ses deniers*).

Quand il y a ambiguïté, ou quand le fournisseur et le destinataire sont tous deux cités, on peut distinguer ce dernier en utilisant ***pour***.

Cette transition est visible dans les différentes éditions du dictionnaire de l'Académie.

> *Acheter une chose **à** quelqu’un, signifie **quelquefois**, L’acheter **de** lui. Je lui ai acheté un volume qu’il m’a fait payer cher. Vous ne sortirez pas de ma boutique sans m’acheter quelque chose. Il signifie aussi, Acheter pour quelqu’un. J’ai acheté une montre à mon fils pour ses étrennes.*
> *Dict. Académie*, 6<sup>e</sup> édition

> *Acheter une chose **à** quelqu’un signifie L’acheter **de** lui. [...]*
> *Dict. Académie*, 8<sup>e</sup> édition (**quelquefois** a disparu)

**Emprunter** est lui aussi utilisé avec ***à*** et ***pour*** (*J'ai emprunté un vélo à mon ami pour mon fils*) mais il n'y a pas d'ambiguïté car on utilise ***prêter à*** si seul le destinataire est cité.